# WordPress. Group advanced custom posts in admin menu

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I use Advanced Custom Post Type UI plugin.

But seems there is no option to group posts in left admin menu.

E.g. I use 3 types of posts in my Index Page, and 2 type of posts on my Category page. I want to see in left admin menu label "Index Page" and when I hover on it I want to see in dropdown all 3 types of posts that used in Index Page.

Is this possible with Advanced Custom Post Type UI plugin, may be anybody do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for that premium option for ACF called `Options Pages`.
Here is [the link](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/)